# F# Fake: Continue on test failure

Tags: .net-core, f#-fake

I am currently trying out FAKE to automate my builds. It works fine so far, but my problem is that the test target fails immediately after one test failed. Instead, I would like it to continue executing all test projects so I get a complete build report with all test results.

My test target looks like this:

```fs
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    trace " --- Run tests --- "
    getAllTestProjectJsons
        |> Array.iter(fun (fileInfo) ->
            (DotNetCli.Test (fun p ->
                {p with AdditionalArgs = ["-xml"; buildTestResultPath testResultDir fileInfo]; WorkingDir = fileInfo.DirectoryName}
                )
            ))
    )
```

where `getAllTestProjectJsons` simply returns an array of `FileInfo` objects with the locations of the `project.json` files of all test projects.

Now, the test target stops executing the different test projects as soon as one test project has a test that fails. What it should do instead is continuing the execution of all test projects and then report whether all tests succeeded or not. Then I can convert the resulting xml files to JUnit format (which is necessary for Bamboo) irrespective of whether a test failed or not.
Other targets like creating nuget packages however should only be executed if all tests succeeded.

Is there an elegant way to do that with FAKE?